# Raise an event on unfocused TimePicker without changing the time

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a `TimePicker` which opens up with already binded time value when `Focused`.

I need to add selected time from `TimePicker` to the previous value when `OK` is pressed but since their is no such events in `TimePicker` so I am using the `Unfocused` event to detect `OK` pressed.

But the `PropertyChange` event is not fired when I click on Ok or Cancel without changing the time in the `TimePicker`.